# excel change values between rows

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet, where columnA represents names, and columnB includes text list of favorite tastes, divided by ",".
I want to reverse the order so columnA will include a single taste and columnB will include list of names.

For example:

**Before:**

```
A    B

Jason
    Vanilla, Strawberry, Jelly

Diana    Chocolate, Whiskey
```

**After:**

```
A        B

Vanilla  Jason, Arthur
```

Thanks
Idan

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to analyse the data in more detail. I would suggest you transform your data (manually or by vba), so that each taste has its own column, and the cell contains a 0 for no and a 1 for yes.

Once this is done, use a pivot table to analyse your data or just a simple row filter if it suffices.